# “Parse issue - Expected identifier"

Tags: objective-c, parsing

I get this error when I try to build my iPhone application:
Parse issue - Expected identifier

My code:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                         options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    self.titleLabel.text = [json objectForKey:@"name"];
    self.aboutText.text = [json objectForKey:@"about"];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL URLWithString: [json objectForKey:@"picture"]];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue
    (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(queue,  ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
        self.profileImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
        });
}
```

I get the error on the line:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL URLWithString: [json objectForKey:@"picture"]];
```

Can someone explain what's wrong?

Comment: Too many left brackets. Try `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [json objectForKey:@"picture"]];`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: Count your brackets carefully.

Comment: The error message isn't really all that cryptic, if you consider it from the compiler's point of view.  It was tooling along nicely and had passed 3 open brackets and two close brackets and so was expecting the next thing to be a method identifier.  But instead it encountered a semicolon.  All it could tell you, with it's tunnel vision, is that it was expecting something that it didn't find.

Answer (score 1):

Unbalanced square brackets is an easy mistake to make because the Xcode will fill in the companion square bracket for you, and it takes a while to get into the habit of pressing the square bracket at the right point in editing a line.

The identifier expected is because instead of ]]; at the end of the line it wants

> ...picture"]] someMethodCallOnANsurl];

and that someMethodCallOnANsurl is the kind of "identifier" it wants